# Implication if a function can be differentiated many times

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have two functions, $f$ and $g$. If $f$ is differentiable more times compared to $g$ (that is, $f$ can be differentiated more times before it reaches a constant), what does it mean with respect to the behavior of both functions?

Comment: When I think about polynomials, $\deg(f)>\deg(g)$ might be what you want.